# Get second match of regex string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to capture the second match in a regex string.

Taking a domain name:

`https://regexrocks.com/my/socks/off`

Replacing everything after `.com`

`$this.val($this.val().replace(/(([^.]*.)[^]?.[^\/]?)/, ''));`

Using the regex:

`(([^.]*.)[^]?.[^/]?)`

Replaces the first match with second: `/my/socks/off`.

https://regex101.com/r/46BIqG/1

**How can I grab the second match?**

Comment: Why the down-vote??? It isn't very helpful if you don't explain the downvote :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is replacing the first match with empty string; leaving the rest of the original string.

try

```
"https://regexrocks.com/my/socks/off".match(/(.*\.com)(.*)/);
```

which will return an array of the capture groups, group 1 at index 1 and group 2 at index 2.

i.e. group 1

```
"https://regexrocks.com/my/socks/off".match(/(.*\.com)(.*)/)[1]; //https://regexrocks.com
```

or group 2

```
"https://regexrocks.com/my/socks/off".match(/(.*\.com)(.*)/)[2]; ///my/socks/off
```

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure if this is user error or not - https://fiddle.jshell.net/tqkv1yuL/1/

Comment: replace

    `$this.val($this.val().match(/(.*\.com)(.*)/));`

with 

    `$this.val($this.val().match(/(.*\.com)(.*)/)[1]);`

Comment: A few minor adjustments and I've got it in order :D `$this.val($this.val().match(/(.*\.[a-zA-Z]+)/)[1]);` does the trick! Update your answer with some input on what the heck just happened to make it work if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to access index 0 of the result from a `match()` instead of using `replace()`:

```
url.match(/(([^.]*.)[^]?.[^/]?)/)[0]
// Should return "https://regexrocks.com"
```

Btw since you're just using a URL, there is another trick you can do using an anchor tag `<a>`:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'http://www.example.com/path/to/something';
console.log(url.origin); // prints "http://www.example.com"
```

For details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Examples

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
\w+:\/\/([\w|\.]+)
```

[code for example](https://regex101.com/r/46BIqG/3)